# How can I sort the column headers in a datagrid alphabetically? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a sorted list that contains the column headers, how do I rearrange my datagridview so it is in the same order as my sorted list?

I've tried the code below but this doesn't always work, some columns are not sorted correctly. Thanks for any help with this.

```
sortedColumnNames.Sort();

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                    {
                        col.DisplayIndex = sortedColumnNames.IndexOf(col.HeaderText);
                    }
```

sortedColumnNames:
athens
crete
corfu
kefalonia
mykonos
rhodes
santorini
skiathos
zante

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell if your problem is that `SortedColumnNames` isn't sorted properly (which it's not), or if the columns are being assigned a different order than what appears in the list.

If it's the latter, it could *conceivably* be because you're modifying the order of items in the collection as you're iterating over it.  Though I'm not seeing that happen in any of the tests I'm running.

Just as a general rule, I don't mess with the membership *or* order of a collection that I'm iterating over.  I implement column-sorting this way:

```
void SortDataGridViewColumns(DataGridView dgv)
{
    var list = from DataGridViewColumn c in dgv.Columns
               orderby c.HeaderText
               select c;

    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in list)
    {
        c.DisplayIndex = i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's something I wouldn't have thought of. Linq.

Comment: My DGV headertexts are actually 4 lines tall, needed to sort by 4th line, then a submember of 2nd line, then 1st line.  Ended up putting string.splits and int.parses in my orderby. Yeah, I know - but I had some terrible requirements.  Solved my problem; thanks!

Comment: This should be marked as the "Answer" to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that should work. I just wrote a quick app to test and it worked fine. Can you nail down exactly when it's working and when it isn't? When you say they don't work, is it always the same columns that are out of order?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

1. Add all columns to List tmpColumns
2. Remove all columns from dgv.Columns
3. Sort tmpColumns by name
4. Add columns back to dgv.Columns from tmpColumns and set while it DisplayIndex to next values 0,1,2 and so on.

It's not ideal, but it works.

Comment: This question/answer helped me. You should credit Robert Rossney with the answer.

Comment: @MrCoincidence If my answer helped you, why i should credit other user? I don't understand your point

Comment: Thomasz, I now understand your comment. My original comment was to the OP asking them to credit you with the answer to the question. Sorry for the confusion.